# Decrease Size of EBS Volume attached to EC2 Instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I've created an EC2 instance with some 100 GB initial size, thereafter I realized this much size is not required, I've to decrease the size now.

##### What I tried?

- Create a new volume with the desired size.
- Attach new volume to ec2 instance.
- Setup New volume (grub-install, EFI partition, etc)
- Copy data from old_volume to new_volume.
- Detach old volume.

But this process is a little bit complex as this can't be smoothly done by all the users, is there any better approach for this?

Comment: The approach you've taken is the only one I know that works. How many volumes do you have that are too large?

Comment: Added my new approach in the answer, (bypass EFI setup process)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps to migrate your ec2 instance data from large volume to small volume.

- Create a new Instance with desired (reduced) volume size and name it `temp-instance`.

  - After the instance is in a running state and status checks are passed, stop the instance, detach this volume and name it as `destination_vol`
- Attach `destination_vol` to the main instance.
- Connect to the main instance and run the below commands.
- Login as root

```
sudo su -
```

- Mount Volumes

```
mkdir /target

mount -t ext4 /dev/nvme1n1p1 /target
```

- Copy data from src to dest

```
rsync -aHAXxSP / /target
```

- Unmount Volumes.

```
umount /target
```

- Stop Main Instance
- Detach both volumes.
- Attach `destination_vol` in mount path `/dev/sda1`
- Start the instance.

**Note:**

- Make sure you set proper AMI, architecture, vpc, etc while creating a temp instance.

**Tips**

- Stuck in Initializing state:

If you followed all the above steps properly and still your instance is in the `initializing` state, you can shutdown and restart the instance.

Answer (score 0):

I stuck in Initializing state and tried to reboot many times without any update.
I'm receiving the following error:
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
-Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
-Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
-Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! PARTUUID="" does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

any help!

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/571703)